# Help icon in the stackexchange.com is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stackexchange.com

The help icon in the Stack Exchange site's top bar is not working.

[image: StackExchage.com help link]

I navigate to my [Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) and clicked on that icon, it is not responding. In other sites it is listing the drop down list.

Comment: Just to confirm: i tried it on several devices, it seems to be a general bug...

Comment: @creyD indeed, there is simply some JS code missing, the team did not copy it when copying the HTML.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard why they didn't make a *copying and pasting from Stack Overflow* like many other developers around the world?

Comment: @alexolut most likely this isn't so simple. The code is different, they need to copy specific parts to other parts. Like a puzzle.

Comment: Fixed for now :) Not 100% certain that we've arrived at the final special case layout for SE.com (the fact that it remains a special case presents some problems), but everything shown there _should_ now work. Off to go find and tag a half dozen other oddities that were probably the result of a few missing JS bits there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the help icon is removed from the [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com) top bar. It seems the issue has been fixed.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Help icon removed]